# How can I write a string, then a null byte, then more data using scanf() in the perspective of a buffer overflow?

Tags: c, null, scanf, user-input, buffer-overflow

In the perspective of attacking with buffer overflow a more complex program, I a trying to use a `scanf()` call in the following way :

```
int main(int agrc, char * argv[]) {
    int len = 32;
    char username[32];
   
    printf("Please enter your username: ");
    scanf("%s", username); //scanf that interests me

  
    if (strcmp(username, "admin") == 0) {
        printf("Ok %s! Here is the desired data: ", username);
    } else {
        printf("Sorry you don't have access\n");
    } 
    
    return 0;
}
```

The objective would be to be able to write the buffer `username` with "admin", then a null byte, then some data to overflow on the `len` variable. This way the `strcmp(username, "admin")` would succeed and we would enter the condition, and at the same time would be able to overflow on `len`.

How can I form an input for `scanf()` that would do that ? My main problem is that I don't know how to enter a null byte using the `scanf("%s", username)` function, even though I know that the `scanf("%s", username)` will not stop at a null byte and will keep scanning.

Comment: Input any string equal to or longer than 32 characters and you will have a buffer overflow. And note that the terminal will end its input on *newline* (the `Enter` key), you could use any other program to generate input in the wanted format (as long as it doesn't contain a newline character).

Comment: My problem here is that the strcmp(username, "admin") wont return 1 if i dont put admin then a null byte then more data to overflow. I want to perform an overflow AND have  strcmp(username, "admin") == 1

Comment: `printf 'admin\0foo\n' | ./a.out`

Answer (score 0):

You can create the input using `echo` or `printf` in the shell, and send it as input to your program. You can do the following in Linux, or any other Unix based system.

```
$ printf  'admin\x00abcdefgh' | ./a.out # \x00 is the null byte
$ echo -e 'admin\x00abcdefgh' | ./a.out
```

Comment: Thank you, but how do i then input the content of a.out into scanf() ?

Comment: @Sorenaide That invocation will send the string to the executable.  When the executable (`a.out`) runs, it will make a call to scanf that does exactly what you are asking for.  Do you want the executable to then continue interactively?  It's not clear what you're asking for now.

Comment: Alright I got it, Thank you very much it's exactly what I was searching for. It was just that my executables dont end with anything (not with .out)